# Unexpected runtime error: Could not load main Class

Tags: java

I was trying on some code to better understand the access modifiers. Everything was running great after I added jus one line of code

```
class SomeClass2 {

  protected static void method4() { }
  protected static int x=0;
}
class SomeClass3 extends SomeClass2{

    int c=SomeClass2.x;
    public void somemethod() //Everything was compiling fine until
    {                        //Until I added this method
    SomeClass2.method4();
    }
}
class DemoClass1{
      public static void main(String[] parameters) {
    SomeClass2 sc = new SomeClass2();
    SomeClass3 sc1 = new SomeClass3();

    sc.method4();
    System.out.println(sc1.c);
sc1.somemethod();

  }
}
```

I am getting an error: `Could not find or load main class DemoClass1`
All the classes belong to same directories and same package. And environmental variables are all set too. It was compiling and running fine until I added `somemethod()`. It compiles fine but does not run.

Comment: how are you building this ?eclipse ? I copied your code and created a new class it ran fine ..no error or anything. make sure you do a clean build.

Comment: No I am using notepad to write and cmd (Windows 7) to compile it. Environment Variables are set. Although I put the same code in a different file name, changed all the class names and compiled it and it ran fine and I got output:
0
But my question is why it did not run on an already working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've provided.

Did you rename the file?

The JVM will look for the main method within the class named exactly the same as the file name. In this case your file should be named

```
DemoClass1.java
```

Comment: No. I did not do any change other than add that single method to an already working code. Before that it was compiling fine

Comment: Although I put the same code in a different file name, changed all the class names and compiled it and it ran fine and I got output: 0 somemethod executed(just and SOP i added later) But my question is why it did not run on an already working code

Comment: Your code looks correct, so I would look elsewhere for the problem. It could be any number of reasons involving your development environment, or maybe your system variables. Make sure you are deleting the old .class files before compiling new ones. A build tool like Apache Ant, Maven, or Gradle helps tremendously with this. And above all: Persevere!

Comment: ok thank you. I just thought I could become more fluent in java before I use a build tool and IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. Saved each class on its respective file (`DemoClass1.java`, `SomeClass2.java` and `SomeClass3.java`).

Everything compiled and executed fine, both with and without `somemethod`.

Comment: I do have the DemoClass1.java SomeClass2.java and SomeClass3.java in same directory. Yet I get an error like this

Comment: Although I put the same code in a different file name, changed all the class names and compiled it and it ran fine and I got output: 0 somemethod executed(just an SOP i added later) But my question is why it did not run on an already working code